# How Do I Clone An App

Tags: force.com, app, clone

how do I clone an app so a few users can switch between apps using the Force.com app drop-down menu at the top-right corner.  I want the same objects/functionality etc...for the cloned app.  I have a business case use for some users that need a complete separate app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always clone a record by adding the `clone=1` parameter to the edit url. For example, navigate to `Setup` > `Create` > `Apps` and select your custom app. Add `/e?clone=1` at the end of the url. It should look something like:

```
<instance>.salesforce.com/02u000000000000/e?clone=1
```

Obviously, `<instance>` should instead be whichever instance you are on, and `02u000000000000` the actual Id already displayed in the url.

Comment: @MartinLezer Yeah it's saved me a lot of tedium over the years. I don't use it often, but when I do it's super clutch.

Comment: thank you for the tip.  my only issue now is will the leads/accounts/opps entered in the cloned app also appear in the original app?  I wanted to keep the data separate from one app to the other, but the functionality/objects etc the same which worked when cloning...just a data concern now.  So would I need another instance set up to have separate data?

Comment: @JReed Data is just data, it's not specific to any application. You may need to consider record types or some other feature to separate it. That sounds like a separate (more complicated) question.